# cargo build failed with #[rstest] inside

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

I want to use parametrized testing and found **rstest** that can do this well.

adding:  `use rstest::rstest;` in the `main.rs` file and putting the `#[rstest]` also inside `main.rs` runs fine on `cargo test`

but if I want to build the programm with `cargo build` I got this error

```
| use rstest::rstest;
 |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `rstest`
```

so the question is: How do I have to organize my code to use `#[rstest]` and also be able to build/run the program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending if you want to run the code using `rstest` with the non-test build or not you either have to add `rstest` in your `Cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies]
rstest = "*"
```

or you have to remove the code using `rstest` from non test builds:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
use rstest::rstest;
```

Comment: ``#[cfg(test)]`` in front of use and in front of each test works fine.